# Catching exception of a shell command in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I had to run a shell program exiting with an error from Perl 6, so I've decided to test how it works. 
I've made a `bash` script producing an error to run it from a Perl 6 program:

```perl6
$ cat prog.sh 
echo "error" >&2
exit 1
```

Here is how I call it from Perl 6:

```perl6
put "start";
  try {
    shell "./prog.sh";
  }
put "end";
```

The output shows that the program exited after running the shell command.

```perl6
start
error
The spawned command './prog.sh' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1)
  in block <unit> at b.p6 line 2
```

If I add a `CATCH` block

```perl6
put "start";
  try {
    shell "./prog.sh";
    CATCH { default {} }
  }
put "end";
```

everything is OK, and the program works to the last line:

```perl6
start
error
end
```

So my question: why is it necessary to add the `CATCH` block, while `try` by itself cannot tackle the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shell` doesn't throw the `Exception` until the [`sink`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/contexts#index-entry-sink_context).

The `try` block with only the `shell` in it fully executes without an exception being thrown, returning the last value in the block, which then gets sunk outside the context of the `try`, which then throws the `Exception`.

You can see this with:

```
put "start";
  try {
    shell "./prog.sh";
    'something';
  }
put "end";
```

Now the shell gets sunk inside the `try`, which gets caught by the implicit `CATCH` of the `try`.  The `try` block returns the last value in the block, the 'something', which then gets safely sunk outside the `try`.

You can also force the `sink` to happen inside the `try`:

```
put "start";
try {
   sink shell "./prog.sh"
}
put "end";
```

Your added `CATCH` block is just preventing the `try` block from returning the return value from the `shell`.

You can re-arrange them and see that this still blows up:

```
put "start";
try {
    CATCH { default {} }
    shell "./prog.sh";
}
put "end";
```

The best, most clear way to handle this IMHO would be to check the return from the shell yourself rather than letting it sink and throw the Exception:

```
put "start";
if shell "./prog.sh" {
    say 'ok'
}
else {
    say 'failed'
}
put "end";
```

Comment: @CurtTilems Thank you very much for explaining this mystery! The only question is — why does the `shell` command throw an Exception only after `sink`? Is it a property of the shell itself or the way Perl 6 handles it? The docs on `sink` are very short, so I don't fully understand the concept.

Comment: `shell` returns a `Failure`, which is a wrapper around an `Exception`.  Only when the `Failure` is actually used, or sunk, will it `throw` the `Exception` it wrapped.  You **can** call `.defined` or `.Bool` on a `Failure` without it throwing: the `.Bool` happens if you use it in an `if`, which is what Curt showed in the last code example.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thanks! But what's the reason why it doesn't throw the Exception? To make it possible to use it in `if` block?

Comment: Yes.  and the `.defined` is for when you want to use it in a `with` block.